# turtlebot upstart

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-hydro, rocon, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I use turtlebot 2 with hydro version. I want to run turtlebot_bringup/concert/bringup.concert file from the upstart of my laptop. I tried to use robot_upstart package, but it works only for launch files and not concert files.

How can I configure the concert file to run from an upstrat?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111886/turtlebot-upstart/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will probably need to script it yourself or extend robot_upstart.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0